# React Native uploading Image to php page on server

Tags: php, react-native, axios, fetch

I have PHP page on a web server to upload image from React Native.

Using Postman method POST, `form-data key:avatar value: image_file` everything works as expected.

In React Native I tried:

```
let uploadData = new FormData();
uploadData.append('avatar', uploadUri);
fetch(base_url, { method: 'post,', body: uploadData }).then(
  (res) => {
    var myresponse = res;

    console.log(JSON.stringify(myresponse));
    //console.log(res);
  }
);
```

I am getting from server error:

> {"type":"default","status":400,"ok":false,"headers":{"map":{"server":"Apache","connection":"Upgrade,
>   close","content-type":"text/html","vary":"Accept-Encoding,User-Agent","date":"Wed,
>   20 May 2020 15:29:15
>   GMT","accept-ranges":"bytes","upgrade":"h2,h2c"}},"url":"http://www./uploadImage.php","_bodyInit":{"_data":{"size":10154,"offset":0,"blobId":"D8041FEE-0479-4CD5-8438-4EFD737561DE","type":"text/html","name":"uploadImage.php","__collector":{}}},"_bodyBlob":{"_data":{"size":10154,"offset":0,"blobId":"D8041FEE-0479-4CD5-8438-4EFD737561DE","type":"text/html","name":"uploadImage.php","__collector":{}}}}

Than I tried using axios:

```
let uploadData = new FormData();
uploadData.append('avatar', uploadUri);
axios.post(base_url, uploadData).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

I get this response from the server:

> "error": true,
>   "message": "No file was sent!",
>   "status": "error",

It is failing on: `if($_FILES['avatar'])`, in PHP.

I have no idea what to do any more, again in Postman everything works fine as expected.

Does anybody have any idea what to do?

I tested it again and it is to be a problem with the URI that I am sending, for sure.

ie. if I look in Postman the request that I am sending:

```
avatar=@/Users/......image.jpg
```

and in React Native I am sending:

```
"avatar","file:///Users/.....image.jpg
```

By the way, I am using expo-image-picker to select the image.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this did the work..

```
let body = new FormData();
                            //Appending file to body
                            body.append('avatar', {
                                uri: uploadUri,
                                type: 'image/jpeg', //This is the file type .. you can define according to your requirement
                                name: 'avatar.jpg', //File name you want to pass
                            });
                            //Service call
                            fetch(base_url, {
                                method: 'POST',
                                headers: new Headers({
                                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                }),
                                body: body,
                            })
                                .then((res) => res.json())
                                .then((responseJson) => {
                                    //GET RESPONSE SUCCESS OF FAILURE
                                    console.log(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
                                })
                                .catch((error) => {
                                    //ERROR
                                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                                });
```